# Can I point my DNS to an IP with a non-standard port for HTTP

Tags: domain-name-system, http

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to redirect domain to specific port](https://serverfault.com/questions/74362/how-to-redirect-domain-to-specific-port)

I have a domain and I want the domain to be like this:

example.com  -> 32.432.32.34:99

Is this possible?

Comment: I know this duplicates an existing question, but I can't find it...

Comment: Only *one* duplicate?  I'm pretty sure I've seen this one several times this week.

Answer (score 6):

DNS is only for IP mapping.  However, you could use a redirect to do a HTTP 302 and point to the IP:port.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: no

Comment: In an effort to provide more info, I found this:

DNS does not have the concept of "port number" in its
records. (This was completely true in the past but is not
quite the case today with SRV records which do include
a concept of service and thereby in some sense port.)

So ignoring SRV records (which practically no clients
except AD domain clients trying to reach DCs would use)
you cannot use DNS for this but much rather do such
routing on the "application server" (e.g., the Web server
usually.) 

http://help.lockergnome.com/windows2/Create-record-redirect-specific-port--ftopict476288.html

Answer (score 0):

no you cannot specify a port.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a redirection service that will handle this for you.  Basically respond on port 80 and send an http redirect 301/307 to your intended location.