# Set up DNS or F5 VIP to send traffic to a specific port

Tags: domain-name-system, sql-server-2008, f5-big-ip

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to use DNS to redirect domain to specific port on my server](https://serverfault.com/questions/74362/how-to-use-dns-to-redirect-domain-to-specific-port-on-my-server)

I have a clustered SQL instance set up at SERVER01\dev08

It's assigned to a static port of 1466.  Can I set up something which will let users connect to SERVER01 and hit that port?

If this is possible, what problems might it create (all traffic coming to this name hitting only one port)?

It seems that DNS has nothing to do with ports - nor does the F5 big IP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing that may have a prayer of working is using a DNS SRV record.  Chances are it won't work though for all (or even most) applications.

You will likely have to configure the clients to use your port when they connect.