# DNS Records: Forwarding a port on my public domain

Tags: domain-name-system, port

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to use DNS to redirect domain to specific port on my web server](https://serverfault.com/questions/74362/how-to-use-dns-to-redirect-domain-to-specific-port-on-my-web-server)

I've set up an MX record for a local mailserver before, but I've never done this...

I want to set up my public domain (registered by Dreamhost) to accept IPP (Internet Printing Protocol) jobs and send them to the IPP LaserJet printer on my home LAN.  IPP uses port 631.

What do I put in my DNS records?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

DNS doesn't do anything with ports, it's strictly for mapping names to IP addresses.  What you need to configure is your firewall to accept connections to port 631 on your public IP and to forward those to the (presumably) internal IP address of the printer.

Comment: And be aware that your public ip address is likely to be at least somewhat dynamic if it's a home isp connection. I'd be considering whether you actually need to do this or if there's a better solution.

Answer (score 2):

In his/her comment to Ward's answer kaerast makes a good point. It might be a whole lot simpler to use DynDNS or similar and print directly to your home connection. Of course we are now in the realms of Super User. not Server Fault.