# 2 services running in a Win 2008 Server with DNS and Port problem

Tags: domain-name-system, iis-7, port

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to use DNS to redirect domain to specific port on my server](https://serverfault.com/questions/74362/how-to-use-dns-to-redirect-domain-to-specific-port-on-my-server)

I have a server running 2 servers. One is IIS7 on 80 port and the other one is Jira 4.1 on the port 8080.

The name of this machine is Jira and can be accessed from anywhere in my network but I'm having a problem that I don't know how to fix... it's a simple one but still, I am not a server guy.

When I type on the browser http://jira , I was hoping it would take me to the Jira instance on the port 8080 but instead, it is taking me to the IIS7 page.

How can I make it go to the Jira server without having to type on the browser "http://jira:8080" and without changing the default ports of the services?

Well, it sounds a bit non-sense but I hope someone here will understand and help me!

Much appreciated!

Cheers

Fred Kaiser

Answer (score 0):

DNS cannot be used to specify ports. Therefore, it's not possible to do what you want, at least not using DNS. It can be achieved through the use of a proxy server or through port forwarding, but that may be more complexity than you are ready for if you are "not a server guy".

Comment: so, is it easier for me to ask the people that host that server to change to ports (IIS 8080 and Jira 80) or ask them to do some port forwarding?

thanks for your prompt answer mate!

Comment: @Fred, that's by far the easiest, if they are cooperative. I'm not even sure if Windows can do port forwarding without putting another machine in front of it (never tried).

Comment: sweet as. I thought I could do it myself rather than waiting for the company that host this server... sometimes it's a bit of a pain to deal with them. anyway, your answers were very helpful John! appreciate that! cheers