# How to get an A entry to map ports?

Tags: domain, ip, redirect, cname-record, mapping

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to use DNS to redirect domain to specific port on my server](https://serverfault.com/questions/74362/how-to-use-dns-to-redirect-domain-to-specific-port-on-my-server)

So here's the deal: I have a domain (say, `mydomain.net`) that I want to create subdomains for. Specifically, I want, say, `crm.mydomain.net` to map to `xxx.yyy.zzz.www:5555` where the letters refer to an IP address. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ports are not part the "normal" DNS system. There's no way to add a port to a A or CNAME record.

Side Note: Some software supports SRV records which do include a port number. This is very uncommon and I don't know of any web browsers which support this (which is probably what you're asking about).

If the websites are one the same machine, you can use host headers to differentiate. I'm guessing you've got Dynamics CRM installed; which defaults to port 5555; you can add an additional binding in IIS for port 80 with a specific host header.
If they're on different machines,  you can use a reverse proxy to send traffic to each machine as is appropriate. ISA Server or [Forefront TMG](http://www.microsoft.com/forefront/threat-management-gateway/en/us/default.aspx) can do this; or there's dedicated devices, alternates like HAProxy, Squid, etc, etc.

Answer (score 0):

if your app on 5555 is web-based :

create an "A" record in dns for crm.mydomain.net to point to xxx.yyy.zzz.www

on the machine that is xxx.yyy.zzz.www setup a website on port 80. use redirection (from the webserver or from the default doc) to automatically do a html redirect to http://crm.mydomain.net:5555

in a defualt doc, it would look like :

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="REFRESH" content="0;url=http://crm.mydomain.net:5555"></HEAD>
</HTML>
```

Comment: This really doesn't help. I want *everything* on port 80.

Comment: @Dmitri, If this is Dynamics CRM, it only installs to port 5555 if you do not use the Default IIS Site and have the installer create an additional site. If you do not have a website on Port 80 on the machine, you can disable the Default Site and add Port 80 to the CRM Site. If you're disabling Port 5555 you have to run the client deployment wizard again, as the configuration file they pull from the server has to be updated with the new port. I'd strongly suggest talking this over with the MS Partner you purchased the software from.