# Domain redirection by port to another server

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, domain-name-system, iis, rackspace

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to use DNS to redirect domain to specific port on my server](https://serverfault.com/questions/74362/how-to-use-dns-to-redirect-domain-to-specific-port-on-my-server)

I have 2 public facing web servers on Rackspace Cloud Servers. One is a Windows 2003 server with IIS 6 and the other a Debian Lenny server with Apache2.

Our old website is hosted on Windows and we are developing a new version from scratch on Debian. The Debian box has Staging and Development environments setup on different ports.

In Rackspace's DNS settings I have the domain for the site pointing to the Windows box but I need to redirect the domain if it's on one of the Staging or Development ports. How can I do this?

Also, it doesn't matter which server does the redirection but I have a preference for Apache since we will eventually move everything over to the Debian box.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a different hostname for your staging and development sites.

DNS has no concept of *ports*. It simply "maps" a hostname to an IP address and its job is done.

So if your "*the site*" is located at www.thesite.com you'll see an `A record`* in your DNS like so:

```
www.thesite.com.    IN   A    1.2.3.4
```

<sub>*Or possibly a series of CNAME records that eventually references to an A record</sub>

I suggest adding records similar to the following:

```
www.staging.thesite.com.       IN   A    1.2.3.5
www.development.thesite.com.   IN   A    1.2.3.5
```

Which will point the staging and development sites to your box running Apache. Then you simply configure Apache with [name-based virtual hosts](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/name-based.html) so that the appropriate site is loaded based on the hostname used to access the site.

I do not recommend mucking around with multiple ports for your dev and staging sites, it's unnecessarily confusing and addresses a problem that doesn't exist if you're using name-based virtual hosts.