# DNS record, paths and port

Tags: domain-name-system, port

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to use DNS to redirect domain to specific port on my web server](https://serverfault.com/questions/74362/how-to-use-dns-to-redirect-domain-to-specific-port-on-my-web-server)

I have a domain xyz.com and a web application running at http://AAA.BBB.CCC.DDD:8080/pcc.

When the user enters the URL xyz.com and www.xyz.com, I want that the page on http://AAA.BBB.CCC.DDD:8080/pcc is displayed in the browser.

What DNS records should I add?

Update:

1) I changed the port to 80.

2) Thanks all for the help!

Now I can reach the application via URLs

www.xyz.com/pcc
xyz.com/pcc ,

i. e. xyz.com and www.xyz.com point to AAA.BBB.CCC.DDD.

One last thing remains: I want xyz.com to point to the pcc directory (as well as www.xyz.com).

How can I do that?

Comment: Now I changed the port to 80, so that now the target URL is http://AAA.BBB.CCC.DDD/pcc

Comment: -1 for [using the wrong tool for the job and then asking how to get the tool to do the job](http://homepage.ntlworld.com./jonathan.deboynepollard/FGA/put-down-the-chocolate-covered-banana.html).  This is a HTTP problem.  DNS is not the tool for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create an [A](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_DNS_record_types) record for xyz.com that points to AAA.BBB.CCC.DDD. You need to create a [CNAME](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CNAME_record) record for www.xyz.com that points to xyz.com.

By default HTTP uses port 80. If you are using apache then you should be able to use [mod_proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_proxy.html) to shift the port.

Comment: Now xyz.com and www.xyz.com both point to AAA.BBB.CCC.DDD, and the port is 80 now (see above). I can reach the application using xyz.com/pcc. But how can I make xyz.com point to AAA.BBB.CCC.DDD/pcc (so that I can reach the app via xyz.com) ? TIA

Comment: if you are using Apache then set the DocumentRoot to /path/to/pcc. Servername xyz.com. ServerAlias www.xyz.com.

Answer (score 4):

The fact that you have your web site running off of a non-standard port web server breaks the ability of a web browser from reaching it without specifying it port - so "http://xyz.com:8080" work, but "http://xyz.com" will not.

This is not a DNS issue, but an application server setup issue. You need something to respond on port 80 for xyz.com if you want the web browsers to be able to contact it without specifying the non-standard 8080 port.

Comment: "I want xyz.com to point to the pcc directory (as well as www.xyz.com)." Why not just park your web server's web root at the pcc directory?

Answer (score 0):

I use zoneedit.com as my DNS provider.  It offers a web forward feature that does this for me.  But it does so by answering on port 80 and forwarding to the correct page for me.  So user48838 is correct in why this won't work, but there may be an alternative.

Comment: The forwarding service will work. The possible "trick" with this situation is finding one or a combination of to host the xyz.com domain and forward to the non-standard port web server.

Comment: To be clear:  I use zoneedit to forward www.mydomain.com to host.mydomain.com:82/myapp.   it works great.  No trick (other than to think to do it)

Comment: I'm in agreement, that does work. There are some pretty "rough" folks that hang out here...

Answer (score 0):

Setup a web browser than can do Rewrites, like Apache, thought hat may be overkill, then add a record:

```
RewriteRule .* http://aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd:8080/pcc [R=301,L]
```

To an `.htaccess` file in your docroot, or in the Apache main `httpd.conf` file.

Comment: This will work if port 80 is accessible on the machine you are running apache on.