# Point domain to IP address with a different port

Tags: domain

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to redirect domain to specific port](https://serverfault.com/questions/74362/how-to-redirect-domain-to-specific-port)
>   [DNS record, paths and port](https://serverfault.com/questions/279711/dns-record-paths-and-port)

I'm registering my domain name with namecheap.com, and I have a VPS. I'm running two websevers: Abyss (port 80) and Node (port 100).

I have two domain names. I'm pointing (A record) the first to my IP address, and it's working fine. For the second, I want to point it to IP Address:100 so that it links to the Node server.

Unluckily, that doesn't work on my settings panel on namecheap.

Any solutions?