# IIS host header non 80 port

Tags: domain-name-system, iis, port, http-headers, host

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to use DNS to redirect domain to specific port on my server](https://serverfault.com/questions/74362/how-to-use-dns-to-redirect-domain-to-specific-port-on-my-server)

I have deployed our company intranet website to  IIS 7 server added the following binding info 

IP Address: All Unassigned 
port: 3333 
domain name: subdomain_name.domain_name.com

I have added the entry in dns also. I can ping the fully qualified domain name but when I throw it in the browser I get 404.

When the site is deployed under port 80 it works just fine. However, it doesnt work when my site is hosted on anything other then the default port (80). 

Is there a way to do this? I want to access my site deployed on port 3333 like the following: subdomain.domain.com

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to access it like so:

```
subdomain.domain.com:3333
```

Furthermore, you could set up an alias on your domain controller to access it with a friendlier URL, saving colleagues from having to remember port numbers and whatnot.

Note that this most likely belongs on the Server Fault Stack Exchange site, I have voted to migrate it there for your own benefit, as that site is dedicated such topics and you ought to gain the advantage of much more experience and expertise than I can possibly hope to provide.

<sub>Please forgive any loose terminology on the subject of servers.</sub>

Comment: yes i can access it with the port but I was hoping that I didn't have too.  Do I always have to include the port if it is not port 80?

Comment: Yes, since 80 is the only _dedicated_ (or _default_) port for HTTP - in the simplest terms, any others must be explicitly stated.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this with DNS or host header redirects.  You need to do a URL rewrite in order for that to happen.  Have a look at the [**URL Rewrite module**](http://www.iis.net/download/urlrewrite).

Comment: any sample using ***URL Rewrite module*** ?