# how do i set the dns server on godaddy with amazon ec2 tomcat webserver running on port 8080

Tags: amazon-ec2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to use DNS to redirect domain to specific port on my server](https://serverfault.com/questions/74362/how-to-use-dns-to-redirect-domain-to-specific-port-on-my-server)

This question is similar to the one asked here https://serverfault.com/questions/229091/how-do-i-set-the-dns-server-on-godaddy-with-aws except that i need little furthur info. My tomcat webserver is running at a port 8080. So the URL looks actually like http://IP:8080. But i godaddy DNS manager it does not allow to mention port. SO how do i forward the DNS name to this IP and then to this specific port

Answer (score 4):

DNS Translates Domain to IP.

Port is not a part of that game at all.

Comment: OK, but how do i make my URL to go to this IP and to this specific port? Is there any article you can point to?

Comment: There is no way. (http just "hints" your browser to try port 80, http_s_ dose the same for port 443, ftp for 21 and so on...)