# Route 53 - IP:PORT

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-route53

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to use DNS to redirect domain to specific port on my server](https://serverfault.com/questions/74362/how-to-use-dns-to-redirect-domain-to-specific-port-on-my-server)

Using Route 53, how would I make a record point to an IP:PORT?

I have tried using a CNAME but it will never resolve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is impossible. The DNS is only able to map to an IP, not to a port.

Comment: SRV records can in fact refer a query to a specific service port. DNS is absolutely capable of doing this, although not all clients know to look up SRV records initially.