# Can't run webrick on port 80

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hosting

I try to figure out how to point a.b.c.d:3000 to my domain name. Here, a.b.c.d is my IP address.

As per this post:

[How to use DNS/Hostnames or Other ways to resolve to a specific IP:Port](https://serverfault.com/questions/74362/how-to-use-dns-hostnames-or-other-ways-to-resolve-to-a-specific-ipport)

I get the impression that I need to set Webrick to host on port 80, since that is the default assumed port, hence I can map a.b.c.d to my domain name and mydomain.org will reach my site.

Is this a correct assumption or am I going about this the wrong way?

Anyway, I can't get Webrick to use port 80, I get the following error:

`WARN  TCPServer Error: Permission denied - bind(2)`

Checking for listeners on port 80:

```
$ netstat -tlnp
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8089          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3266/banshee    
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN      -
```

No other processes using port 80.

From other posts, I get the impression that mapping to ports below 1024 is not possible.

Running the following command:

`iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080`

Now, setting Webrick on port 8080, I still can't reach my site from a.b.c.d! (nor a.b.c.d:80)

This situation shouldn't be such an uncommon one, what am I missing? If it matters, I use the standard Rails 4 development environment of Webrick, because I only expect like 100 page views/months.

Comment: You'll get more traffic than that every day just from Googlebot. Best to do it right the first time. Apache+Passenger, nginx+unicorn, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Normal users (`uid != 0`) cannot bind ports <1024 on UNIX-like systems. You could do some `iptables` hacks or run Werbick as `root` ([or other means described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/413807/is-there-a-way-for-non-root-processes-to-bind-to-privileged-ports-1024-on-l)) instead, but I would not suggest to do so.

Take a proper webserver like Apache, nginx or lighttpd and let it proxy all the traffic to your Webrick. That should be like 5 lines of configuration and you will end up with a setup that you can control and modify way better.

Answer (score 0):

try running on different port, like run as non-root user on tcp/8080

also, run `lsof |egrep "80|http"`, to see what's running on tcp/80

it may just be webrick is broken... try mod_passenger if that's a rails app