# How can I redirect a subdomain to a different URL via Windows DNS?

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain-name-system

Let's say I have a site called test.website.com that I'd like to forward to www.website.com/test.

How can I achieve this via Windows Server 2008 DNS?

I've configured this for external users via GoDaddy Subdomain Forwarding but I can't seem to figure out how to do this internally via Windows DNS.

I tried setting up a CName to do this and although it will redirect pings to the desired URL, it doesn't seem to work for the website itself.

This seems like something basic but I can't seem to figure it out. Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: @Chris S Care to share where the question has been asked before vs. flagging the post without offering the information?

Comment: The question referenced above is not the same question. I was asking how to redirect to a different URL and that was asking how to resolve to a specific port. This should not be marked as a duplicate.

Comment: The answer [here](http://serverfault.com/a/74371/3038) is the best fit for your problem. DNS will get you as far as the web-server itself, once it's there it's up to the server software to redirect to a different URL. For IIS that would probably be a new name-bound virtual server rooted in the `/test` folder.

Comment: I agree the answer here is the best fit I just don't believe this was a duplicate question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot.  A DNS server doesn't have this feature.

Sites like Godaddy set a DNS record to point at an HTTP(S) server which send out the proper redirects.

Comment: That was what I thought but I figured I would ask ServerFault before putting this on the record here at work. Thanks.