# DNS how to dynamically bind subdomains to ip and port pairs

Tags: networking, domain-name-system, bind, internal-dns

I'm using bind9

I have a zone file setup with a few subdomain A records. I'm wondering if I can create a subdomain record that points to an ip address on a specific port.

I'm currently updating the zonefile dynamically. I'd need some service with an API that can handle an infinite amount of subdomains. Also need to map udp and non http tcp ports.

I think I might need to use ip tables?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, DNS only takes care of name resolution to an IP address. It does not offer the capability to map to a port. This question has a more detailed explanation -- [How to use DNS/Hostnames or Other ways to resolve to a specific IP:Port](https://serverfault.com/questions/74362/how-to-use-dns-hostnames-or-other-ways-to-resolve-to-a-specific-ipport)

Some DNS services allow URL forwarding, which I think should do what you are looking for. For eg NameCheap offers this feature -- https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/545/51/how-do-i-set-up-url-forwarding-when-i-use-your-free-dns-service