# How do I give each Virtual Host in Apache a domain name on a local network?

Tags: apache-2.2, domain-name-system, virtualhost, nameserver, debian-wheezy

### Background information.

I have a server (running Debian Wheezy and Apache 2) at which I am to set up several Virtual Hosts to allow students to host their own website for development purpose. I am facing the simple option (from what I know) to host each site on a different port, making the students access their sites like this:

```
192.168.1.2:80
192.168.1.2:81
192.168.1.2:82
```

Where 192.168.1.2 is the server's local IP and :80-:82 is the ports hosting the different sites.

Although this is an approach that works out what I am actually trying to do, I think that something name based would be much more intuitive. One option is using the router's local domain name, I am not sure of how it works and I haven't got around to implement it successfully. If that worked, they could acccess their sites like this:

```
development.group.com:80
development.group.com:81
development.group.com:82
```

Where development is the server's hostname and group is the router's local domain name (DNS suffix).

What I would like to do, something that would be even more intuitive is to let each user have their own domain name (without actually having/owning one, of course). Example of how that would look:

```
www.exampledomain.com
www.exampledomain2.com
www.exampledomain3.com
```

I am thinking of implementing it by running my own DNS server, telling the router to use that DNS server and make each site hosted on the various domains.

### Question.

I am not quite sure of how I could do that, so I guess the real question is: is there a best / better way of doing this and if not, how do I set up a DNS server (on the same server as the apache one) and make it reroute to the sites hosted by me?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use DNS/Hostnames or Other ways to resolve to a specific IP:Port](http://serverfault.com/questions/74362/how-to-use-dns-hostnames-or-other-ways-to-resolve-to-a-specific-ipport)

Comment: @HBruijn That question does not include how one would go about and implement this without actually having the domain names. (Spoofing/faking domain names) Neither does it question what way is "the way". It answers that DNS cannot be used to forward to a port, but not much else.

Comment: If you can't control the DNS server your users are assigned and therefore can't create classroom domains: the registration of a real domain is nowadays a single digit $/€ amount. Then use subdomains like www.studentN.example.edu.

Comment: I can control the DNS, I have full access to the network router and the server. The server's DNS can be pointed to the Server, but the question is what should be on the recieving end?

Comment: HowTo set a DNS server is not really on topic here. A really trivial DNS server that take the syntax of /etc/hosts as a basis and works as a forwarder for everything else is [dnsmasq](http://www.thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/docs/dnsmasq-man.html)

Comment: @HBruijn After some further reasearch, dnsmasq (using only as DNS) should solve my problem. I will test it later, thanks.