# Transparent url redirection for https site

Tags: https, firefox, url-routing

I'm hosting two new wordpress VM on my network. (on one computer)
[see this diagram on imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iuIcK.png)

I would like to access them by different url/domain name

for example *WP1.mydomain.com* & *WP2.mydomain.com*

or *myfirstDomain.com* & *MysecondDomain.io*

--

Those WordPress are running under https.
I tried an url redirection from my domain name registrar.
but this lead to a [blocking error :/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DJiYA.png) in the browser (firefox)
as you can see there are no way to go further.

If I enter directly my public IP:port (for redirection)
I get almost the same error but at least I have[(Accept the risk and continue)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OIZHN.png)

I understand why those errors occur = http**s**

I'm looking which solutions exist to circumvent those error.

Is a reverse proxy is the only one solution ??

Answer (score 0):

You could refer to this answer posted by another user, however it's not a complete solution and can be a bit finicky. https://serverfault.com/a/460269/551976

I would simply suggest hosting the two WordPress servers on a common linux server with subdomain redirects added in the apache config file. So each subdomain or domain would point to the respective WordPress folders in the linux server.

If you're not sure how to do this you can refer to a WordPress web server hosting tutorial online as that would take a while to learn and would be a bit long to explain here but it would give you your desired result.

Answer (score 0):

You will still need to obtain certs for `myfirstDomain.com` and `MysecondDomain.io`, and have your web server set up to serve those domains on
 SSL port 443.  Get that working first.

On `myfirstDomain.com` use this `index.html`:

```
<title>Your Page Title Here</title>
<frameset frameborder=0 framespacing=0 border=0 rows="100%,*" noresize>
  <frame title="secure content" name="myframe" src="https://WP1.mydomain.com" noresize>
</frameset>
<meta http-equiv=refresh content="0; url=https://WP1.mydomain.com">
<a href="https://WP1.mydomain.com">WP1.mydomain.com</a>
```

On `MysecondDomain.io` use this `index.html`:

```
<title>Your Page Title Here</title>
<frameset frameborder=0 framespacing=0 border=0 rows="100%,*" noresize>
  <frame title="secure content" name="myframe" src="https://WP2.mydomain.com" noresize>
</frameset>
<meta http-equiv=refresh content="0; url=https://WP2.mydomain.com">
<a href="https://WP2.mydomain.com">WP2.mydomain.com</a>
```

With this set up, hits to `https://myfirstDomain.com` should display the content of `WP1.mydomain.com`, and hits to `https://MysecondDomain.io` should display the content of `WP2.mydomain.com`.

Answer (score 0):

A way to solve your issue is to apply transparent URL forwarding to both *myfirstDomain.com* & *MysecondDomain.io*, and point them to *WP1.mydomain.com* & *WP2.mydomain.com* respectively.

Implementing this concept from scratch can be challenging and time-consuming, therefore, as an alternative, you can use an existing solution.

This [configuration guide](https://www.intellisparrow.com/Tturlfw-configuration) explains how to quickly configure a transparent URL Redirect from a *Source domain* to a *Destination domain* with the possibility to set custom SSL certificates. This method is also very secure since it does not use any Frames or IFrames.

A configuration example suitable to *myfirstDomain.com* would be something like this:

- Source Domain = ***myfirstDomain.com***
- Destination Domain = ***WP1.mydomain.com***
- SSL Certificate = **Valid certificate for myfirstDomain.com**
- Force HTTPS = **yes**

for *MysecondDomain.io* you could do the same steps.